# Dynamically reference table row depending on cell input

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

I've found a couple of questions that touch on what I want to do, but not quite.

I have a table, say Table1

| Segment | tot_bad_1at3 | tot_bad_2at6 | tot_bad_3at6 | tot_bad_4at6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 25 | 22 | 15 |
| B | 1 | 11 | 9 | 4 |
| C | 3 | 15 | 12 | 6 |
| D | 4 | 21 | 18 | 12 |
| E | 6 | 8 | 5 | 2 |

Then I have added calculated column to the table, called 'bad', in which I would like one of the existing columns selected based on a user input into Sheet2 cell A2 (called "bad_def"). This is a dropdown with the values: bad_1at3,bad_2at6,bad_3at6,bad_4at6
[image]

Hence the 'pseudo-formula' for table column 'bad' would be `[@["tot_" & bad_def ]]` or `[@[indirect("tot_" & bad_def) ]]`. In otherwords, I simple want the corresponding row in the table returned, depending on the user input.
Another option, is to add a simple calculation to take the user input, and prefix it with "tot_" to create the already existing table column.

Currently, I am using `=INDEX(Table1, ROW([@Segment])-1, MATCH("tot_" & bad_def, Table1[#Headers],0))`, or with a series of nested if statements. Hence I am wondering if there is a more dynamic way to do this?

Appreciate the advice.

Good day all.

Answer (score 0):

To create a dynamic calculated column for this scenario, use the XLOOKUP function (or the INDEX and MATCH functions) to find the *lookup_value* within the table header row, "*Table1[#Headers]*", and return the corresponding value from the current table row, "*Table1[@]*":

```
=XLOOKUP("tot_"&bad_def, Table1[#Headers], Table1[@])
```

OR:

```
=INDEX(Table1[@], MATCH("tot_"&bad_def, Table1[#Headers], 0))
```

NOTE: with the INDEX function, since the *array* parameter only contains a single row, the *row_num* parameter will accept the *column_num* argument.

Also, to avoid any circular reference warnings, do NOT include the column header of the newly created calculated column in the data validation list for "*bad_def*".